# how to prevent 0 in blank textbox event

Tags: c#

[image]

I want to fetch data in texbox1 event and insert that fetched data into another table based on primary key search it doing perfectly like on primary key 8.

[image]

But when I want to enter new data like 9 primary key it adds 0 primary key on blank texbox1 how to prevent this

Comment: Use a auto-incrementing column in the DB - if it's SQLS, set Identity specification for the column

Answer (score 0):

MySQL uses the AUTO_INCREMENT keyword to perform an auto-increment feature.

By default, the starting value for AUTO_INCREMENT is 1, and it will increment by 1 for each new record.

To let the AUTO_INCREMENT sequence start with another value, use the following SQL statement:

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable AUTO_INCREMENT=100;
```

Comment: how to avoid sql primary key 0 on blank textbox event changed for example I fetch data in 8th primary key its doing perfect but when I remove 8th primary key to enter 9 or whatever like 16th primary key data when I remove 8 to do so texbox1 become blank and it enter 0 value in sql table I want to avoid 0 value on blank texbox event

Comment: You don't need input value from textbox when you want to add a new record in your table. It's best for you to delete that textbox and set auto_increment on your primary key (ID)

Comment: Problem has been solved with if (textbox1.text.length >=0) thank you all

Comment: @IrfanDaudpota yes u can do it, but thats not a good choice, because you dont need to insert ID in table. When you have alot of data, you will have duplicate id's, its only way to do it just delete that textbox and set auto increment, but as you wish. Good luck

Comment: YES you are right will change it but for understanding did it thank you.